# PL/SQL raise handled exception

Tags: exception, plsql

How can I throw cached exception in PL/SQL?

For example I have procedure, where I catch all exceptions:

```
  EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      rollback;
```

and then I want to throw catched exception to procedure caller.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `raise;`:

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    rollback;
    raise;
```

Answer (score 2):

To re-raise the exception, just use

```
raise;
```

To define a custom application error, look at [raise_application_error](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS99960), e.g.

```
raise_application_error(-20001, 'Warp core implosion imminent', true);
```

It's worth bearing in mind that due to what I've just decided to call the [Exception Handling Uncertainty Principle](https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2015/07/24/plsql-error-logging-and-quantum-theory/), there is always a trade-off between reporting the full exception details and doing something about the exception.