# Handling exceptions by adding select clause embedded inside in PL-SQL(Oracle functions)

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

I have to design a function(date in, number out) in oracle which executes the following three cases given the conditions:

case1: If input_date matches monday_date then execute query1(select  from  where.. and..) with monday_date as input param.

case2: If query from case(1) returns no rows, then create new variable max_input_date1 = input_date+1 and then execute query2(with ..select  from table1 left join table2 ..) with monday_date and max_input_date1 as input param.

case3: If query from case(2) returns no rows, then create new variable max_input_date2 = input_date+4 and then execute query2( with..select  from table1 left join table2 ..) with monday_date and max_input_date2 as input param.

I am trying to use exception - NO_DATA_FOUND to move to each case, but it looks like exception clause in the oracle functions do not execute any "select" statements - I am not completely sure, but it did not work for me, or I am doing something wrong. nothing is being returned after the function enters the exception clause.

I am looking for suggestions on how to get this to work, either with or without use of exceptions. Please help. This is how my function looks so far

```
CREATE OR
    REPLACE FUNCTION get_dept_no(input_date string)
    RETURN NUMBER
    IS
    dept_no NUMBER;

    max_input_date1 date ;
    max_input_date2 date ;

    delta1 integer := 1;
    delta2 integer := 4;

BEGIN
    SELECT num
    INTO dept_no
    FROM table1
    WHERE aperiod = 201910
      AND trunc(monday_date) = to_date(input_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
    RETURN dept_no;
EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            max_input_date1 := to_date(input_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') + delta1;

            WITH max as (
                SELECT *
                FROM table2 adm
                GROUP BY aperiod, num
                )

                SELECT
                       ma.num INTO dept_no
                FROM max ma
                LEFT JOIN table1 yw
                  ON ma.aperiod = yw.aperiod
                  AND ma.num = yw.num
                WHERE trunc(ma.DOJ_date) >= to_date(input_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                  AND trunc(ma.DOJ_date) <= to_date(max_input_date1, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
            raise;
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                max_input_date2 := to_date(input_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') + delta2;
                WITH max as (
                SELECT *
                FROM table2 adm
                GROUP BY aperiod, num
                )

                SELECT
                       ma.num INTO dept_no
                FROM max ma
                LEFT JOIN table1 yw
                  ON ma.aperiod = yw.aperiod
                  AND ma.num = yw.num
                WHERE trunc(ma.DOJ_date) >= to_date(input_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                  AND trunc(ma.DOJ_date) <= to_date(max_input_date2, 'yyyy-mm-dd');

return dept_no;
END get_dept_no;
```

Comment: Not sure if I follow your issue. What exactly is your function returning? null?

Comment: You cannot handle `WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN` twice in the same EXCEPTION section, this will cause an error: "PLS-00483: exception 'NO_DATA_FOUND' may appear in at most one exception handler in this block"

Comment: Please review [ask]. Following that as a template for your question greatly enhances your chances of getting  a satisfactory answer. In this case table DDL and sample data with expected result on that data. Also what result you get but a as guess I would venture "ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value"  or "ORA-01403 no data found".

Comment: Right now, the function returns a row with case1 satisfied and executed, I am unable to move to case 2 or case 3, and I am need help with writing case 2 and case 3 . When the function enters the exception it does not execute the query inside the exception section and returns null, where it should have returned a row. @Acroyear

Comment: There are no errors produced when I compile and build the function @Belayer, but if you let me know what is unclear, I can try to explain.

Comment: @Tony Andrews I read in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767142/pl-sql-raise-handled-exception that you can, I probably understood it wrong, could please you suggest how I can code my requirements into the function then, if not using the exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to want to write very small functions that do exactly 1 thing; that sometimes surprisingly involves more code, but removes complexity - seems like a contradiction but not really. In this case I would break it 3 inner functions, and a simple main. (Yes, you can write a function inside on a function).

```
create or replace function get_dept_no(input_date IN string)
    return number
is
    dept_no number;

    max_input_date1 date;
    max_input_date2 date;

    delta1 integer := 1;
    delta2 integer := 4;

    function get_dept_q1
      return number
    is
        dept_q1_result number;
    begin 
        select num
          into dept_q1_result
          from table1
         where aperiod = 201910
           and trunc(monday_date) = to_date(input_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
        return dept_q1_result;
    exception 
       when no_data_found then 
            return null; 
    end get_dept_q1;  

    function get_dept_q2
      return number
    is
        dept_q2_result number;
    begin 
      max_input_date1 := to_date(input_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') + delta1;

      with max as (
           select *
             from table2 adm
            group by aperiod, num
            )
       select ma.num  
        into dept_no
        from max ma
        left join table1 yw
             on  ma.aperiod = yw.aperiod
             and ma.num = yw.num
         where trunc(ma.doj_date) >= to_date(input_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
           and trunc(ma.doj_date) <= to_date(max_input_date1, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
        return dept_q2_result;         
    exception 
       when no_data_found then 
            return null; 
    end get_dept_q2;  

    function get_dept_q3
      return number
    is
        dept_q3_result number;
    begin 
      max_input_date1 := to_date(input_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') + delta1;

      with max as (
           select *
             from table2 adm
            group by aperiod, num
            )
       select ma.num  
        into dept_q3_result
        from max ma
        left join table1 yw
              on  ma.aperiod = yw.aperiod
             and ma.num = yw.num
         where trunc(ma.doj_date) >= to_date(input_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
           and trunc(ma.doj_date) <= to_date(max_input_date1, 'yyyy-mm-dd');
         return dept_q1_result;
    exception 
       when no_data_found then 
            return null; 
    end get_dept_q3;       

-- MAIN    
begin
   dept_no := get_dept_q1;

   if dept_no is null 
   then 
      dept_no := get_dept_q2;
   end if;

   if dept_nun is null 
   then 
      dept_no := get_dept_q3;
   end if;                                                     

   if dept_num is null 
   then 
      raise no_data_found; 
   end if;

   return dept_no;
end get_dept_no;
```

NOTE: I did not evaluate the queries, just restructured the original function.

Comment: Wow this is neat! I get what you are saying, I will try it out. But I think this is what I needed, to find a way to structure the cases. Thank you. @Belayer Will let you know ho wit works out

Comment: So I tried it and this structure definitely works and also answers my question. I have marked it to accepted. Thanks a lot! None of cases are not returning any result yet upon function call yet, but I think I need to figure out the flow of data here. As far as the function goes, it compiles and builds without errors!

Comment: Happy to help. This is an approach I often use. It allows testing/debug in little pieces making both MUCH simpler. And if the nested function are generally useful I'll make then into a schema level functions. If that were done here your main routine reduced to 10-12 or so. Disclaimer: There is a performance penalty to be paid with this approach. But the ability to keep the code clear and understandable it is a price gladly pay - at least until I get unacceptable performance level.

Comment: Totally agreed! @Belayer - would you be able to help me understand what I could be doing wrong using this structure that the basic function which initially worked, which is now a form of the function, is returning no rows at all? I was hoping to not add another question for that..

Comment: I don't know. As I indicated this structure (I assume you mean the new) is easier to test and debug.  But to do so requires the code, data, expected output and current output (even of that is none, if so state so). To that end I suggest posting another question, you can link to this one.